# Sent messages from iPhone don't show on macbook messages

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, messages

I use iMessage for my iPhone and Macbook.

The problem:

I can't see a message I sent from my iPhone on my Macbook, but I can see a sent message from my Macbook on my iPhone. How can I see sent messages from my iPhone on my Macbook?

Receiving messages work on iPhone and Macbook.

Edit:

I followed the [guidelines](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681#SMS) from Apple but the problem still persists. These are my specs:

- iPhone 6s running iOS 11.3.1.
- Macbook Pro 2015 running High Sierra 10.13.3.

Comment: Is Continuity setup on both devices?  See [this Apple post](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681#SMS) about how to set it up for Messages then come back and [edit] your answer.  Also, please include your iOS and macOS versions.

Comment: @fsb Thanks for your reply! I read the Apple post but the problem still persists - I updated my question according to your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for adding the updates.  Please verify if you have wifi and bluetooth turned on for both devices and that you have `Text Message Forwarding` on your iPhone to your Mac turned on.

Comment: @fsb Thank you for your reply. I verified that both devices are on the same network and have their bluetooth turned on. Text Message Forwarding is also enabled - whenever I get a message or SMS I receive the message on my Macbook. I also tried to disable/enable iMessage on iPhone and Macbook but without success: I still can't see the sent messages from my iPhone on my Macbook.

Comment: Take a look at [this troubleshooting page](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-sync-imessage-on-iphone-ipad-mac-3654385/) and make sure you're following all the steps.  Until the updated versions of iOS and macOS  that keep Messages on both devices in sync, missing any of these steps could cause it not to work properly.

Comment: @fsb None of these steps worked. The problem was on the Macbook Pro though - I fixed it by reinstalling macOS - next time I should create a time machine backup instead. Thanks for your help and advice!